# How can I prevent injuries?

Tags: fifa-12

In FIFA 12 Ultimate Team, my players get injured a lot, sometimes 3 players in the same match.

I figured a good fitness value would prevent this, but now I am not even sure those two are related.

How can I effectively prevent injuries in FUT?

Comment: Fitness level means nothing i have bassong (CB) and he had 99 fitness before the game and after the game it said he was out for 4 games aswell as 3 other of my players

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 main factors;

A player becomes more injury prone when fitness is lower. Use fitness cards to keep your star players topped up, and use rotation to give your other players a rest.

A players physical attributes (strength, stamina) also play a part. There are also 1 or more hidden characteristics for injury proneness, so if you notice a player who gets injured a lot, it might be time to replace him.

Answer (score 0):

What I tend to do is have a full team, so all 18 players! I make sure they are all pretty decent quality so that playing with my second team wont be too much of a dramatic difference!

What you want to watch is their fitness after each game (the players) I tend to change them once the reach 80's which is high, I know. But they all seem to get injured around that time, so switch the players around, the others regenerate while on the bench and in the reserves, hope this helped.

Get back to me with results!